# Minimizing Frobenius Norm subject to a constraint

Tags: matrices, optimization, regression, linear-regression

I have the following problem:

$ \min_{A} || A - X||_{F}\\s.t.
\theta = (A^TA)^{-1}A^Ty$

where $A$ and $X$ are $n\space x \space p$ matrices and $y$ is a $n\space x \space 1$ vector.

$\theta$ is the estimates of the population parameters in linear regression with OLS $(\hat{\beta})$.

I am thinking of using the Lagrangian. However, although it is fairly easy to minimize the Frobenius norm without the constraint, I am not sure how to integrate the constraint into the Lagrangian as it is a equation involving matrices and vectors.

Comment: what are free variables and fixed variables?

Comment: @zimbra314 , the fixed ones are $\theta$, X, and y.

I am trying to find the A that would solve the minimization problem subject to the constraint.

Comment: $L(A,\lambda) = \lVert A-X \rVert_F^2 + \lambda^T\left[ \left(A^T A \right)^{-1} A^T y - \theta \right]$...

Comment: @user550103 is $\lambda$ a vector or a matrix? And what's its size?

Comment: $\lambda$ is a vector should have the same size as $\theta$

Comment: @user550103 but why? I am trying to find the A that would minimize this whole thing. A is a matrix. If A is of size nxp, that means there are np variables I have to find. In that case, shouldn't I have nxp entries in $lambda$?